# How does MRI parse the `||=` operator?

Tags: ruby

Today I was trying to explain to a coworker that `||=` is not thread-safe in MRI. I figured I'd take a look at the Ruby source to try and see if I could point out the spot where Ruby scheduler could switch the thread context, but I'm having trouble navigating the code. I was hoping someone more experienced could walk me through the files that are hit.

So far I know that Bison takes the `parse.y` and generates a `parse.c` file which calls some underlying functions. I see that `||` is parsed as `tOROP` but then I get a bit lost on what happens next

Also is there some tool like Ripper that I can use to make this process a little easier? (And on that note it would be helpful if someone could point me to where the Ripper source code is defined)

Comment: It's a non-atomic operation, so it's not thread-safe. What's the specific question here? If you need thread safety you have to ask for it.

Comment: What makes it non-atomic? I would like to be able to follow the source code to see what makes that true.

Comment: Just as `x += 1` is non-atomic. It requires a read, compare, and (conditional) assignment. `x ||= y` is effectively `x = x || y` or `x = y unless (x)` depending on how particular you want to get. Notice in both cases a read and compare (not *false*) is required prior to assignment. Anything can happen in that gap. You may want to look at what byte-code MRI expresses that statement as to know what's going on internally.

Comment: @tadman  Why would anything that is non-atomic become thread unsafe?

Comment: This issue I'm having is trying to get to that byte-code. I understand how things work under the hood at a high level, but I'm hoping for a practical hand-holding for this particular example (e.g. which line of parse.y is being triggered)

Comment: MRI's `ruby` has a `--dump` option. I think you're looking for `--dump yydebug` but you might be also interested in `parsetree` or `insns`.

Comment: @WandMaker Where you have two instructions, there's always the *possibility* that something might happen in the middle. Explicitly atomic operations either succeed or fail, they cannot be interrupted by definition, and are always thread-safe. For more low-level examples, [Intel has an explanation](https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/506090) worth reading. The general principle here is that unless you're employing a lock of some sort or using atomic operations on *shared* values, you're not thread-safe.

Comment: @cremno Very nice! That's definitely a big help `ruby -e "@hello ||= 'hi'" --dump parsetree` seems like it should be very useful

Comment: @tadman That's a great link! I think under-specified my question before. I'm assuming that we're using the GIL here and wondering where the GIL is released during the operation `||=` and what that source looks like

Comment: The GIL means that no two threads are active at precisely the same time, however it doesn't mean that your operation will run to completion within any given lock. Multiple threads are constantly competing for the same lock and one may assume control in the middle of an `||=` operation, after the read but before the write.

Comment: So what I think that means is that a thread gets control of the lock, performs the read, then releases the lock. I guess that's the part of the source that I'm trying to find: what code manages the GIL. That should explain the level at which the locking occurs at (e.g. does it lock each instruction as dumped by `ruby -e "@hello ||= 'hi'" --dump insns`?)

Comment: I think it _might_ be "accidentally" thread-safe in MRI (but not JRuby). I understand what you're asking, and I don't know where the C code is to point you to it, but I've seen articles on it before perhaps you can find googling. In MRI, you are right that the GIL is only released at certain points, and it's possible `||=` might end up accidentally thread-safe, but even if so its an implementation detail, subject to change, and not safe in other interpreters.

Comment: Thread safety has nothing whatever to do with the parser. Stop looking there. The ||= is rewritten as a sequence of operations (view the assembly code) and that sequence can be interrupted, during which another thread can change the value which was read for the conditional.

Comment: "Which one of these things doesn't belong (in the question)?" The last paragraph. Please don't ask for recommendations for off-site resources as it's off-topic. The gist of the question is great but you're missing detail, as evidenced by the long list of comments but no viable answers.

Comment: @tadman, The GIL in Ruby has different behavior depending of the Ruby version. In Ruby 1.8.x The GIL has only one native thread but in 1.9.x there are many native threads. Further, other implementations of Ruby like JRuby implements all threads as natives, check out this [link](https://www.igvita.com/2008/11/13/concurrency-is-a-myth-in-ruby/)

Answer (score 1):

Forgetting the parser, if you look at the code [in compile.c here](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/compile.c#L4528-L4564) you'll see how the instructions are generated to handle the assignment-or operation. Each call to ADD_INSNL emits an instruction. At line 4553 you see an *if* condition, which tests the value of the LHS after it was read by code emitted via the call to the COMPILE macro at line 4546, in order to decide whether to assign the new value. During this time, another thread may supervene and change the value that was read, so the assignment is done (or not done) when it shouldn't be.

As for how the NODE_OP_ASGN_OR is created, see the call to NEW_OP_ASGN_OR (defined in node.h) called from parse.y in function new_op_assign_gen().

Hopefully the line numbers won't change too soon, and invalidate these URLs.